# Copy files from github via SSH using SCP

Tags: github, ssh, scp

I'm trying to download a file from github repository and I would like to use ssh (using scp) instead of downloading it via HTTPS. Is that even possible? Could you give an example? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No it's not possible. Git repositories don't consist of the actual files, but a collection of the incremental changes.

Therefore you have to clone a repository to get the file.
Github only offers the HTTPS download as "services".

Comment: What about the "github releases" files? They're just files :)